# Running sudo commands through pxssh

Tags: python, pexpect

I am using the pxssh module to connect to a remote server though ssh. I use the following function to send commands

```
def send_command(session , cmd):
    session.sendline(cmd)
    session.prompt()
    return session.before
```

This works perfectly for commands like `ls` , `pwd` , etc.

Problem :

When I enter commands that request authentication or user input like `sudo`, `vim` , the program hangs and it returns nothing. How do we get around this ?

Comment: how are you inputting the password?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, what password do you mean? when I use sudo for root commands in the function it doesn't return anything and I cannot enter the password for the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `send_command()` with commands that expect user interaction e.g., to provide a password.

```
session.sendline(cmd)  # program started 
# put here user interaction 
# ... expect('(?i)password:'); sendline(passwd) ...         
session.prompt()       # program ended (the shell prompt is shown)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of  expect('(?i)password:'); in the code ? Is it a built-in function ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. One more question, I don't understand the purpose of prompt(). It says in the documentation that it matches the prompt. What does that mean ?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: if you don't understand what "matches" (look at all `.expect()` calls in the documentation) or "the prompt" (what do you see on the left of each command that you run in the terminal?) means in the context of `pexpect` module then [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).